# почему не добавляется класс?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$("input").on('click',function () {
    let sas=$([this.checked]>['span']);

    if(sas=true){
          $(sas).addClass('goooo');

    }else {
        $(sas).removeClass('goooo');
    }


});
```

как добавить класс span,который находится в свою очередь в input,у кого есть атребут чекед?

Comment: какому именно span Нужно добавить класс? или всем span На странице?

Comment: <label for="Monday"><input type="checkbox"  id="Monday"><span></span> Понедельник </label>
нужно добавлять спану,который в свою очередь лежит в input)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проверить флаг `checked` можно с помощью свойства [`checked`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement)

Для выбора элемента следующего за `input` можно воспользоваться методом [`next`](https://api.jquery.com/next/)

Для установки или снятия класса, в зависимости от условия можно воспользоваться методом [`toggleClass`](https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/#toggleClass-className-state)

Исходя из этого, код может принять следующий вид:

```
$("input").on('click',function () {
    $(this).next().toggleClass('goooo', this.checked);
});
```